# 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, while hosting website using Firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, web-hosting

I am trying to host my website using Firebase. According to firebase documentation I should use the command "npm install -g firebase-tools" to install Firebase command line tools using npm. 
My command prompt returns the error " 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
How do I rectify this.

Comment: First install nodejs and then fire that command

Comment: Where are you trying to run this command?

Comment: It’s exe file which provide commands access

Comment: Thank you. I've found the answer. I needed to add "C:\Program Files\nodejs" to my Environment variables under PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I needed to add the path of the nodejs folder to the **Path** variable of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.
You must first make sure you have installed Node.js. If you haven't, download from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

The path is ->  C:\Program Files\nodejs

**File Explorer** -> **This PC** -> **Right click and select Properties** -> **Advanced System Settings** -> **Environmental Variables** -> **Select Path** -> **Edit** -> **New** -> **C:\Program Files\nodejs** -> **OK**

Open the cmd again and npm will now run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Node first, Download and install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). npm is `Node package manager` that comes with node.

Comment: can you confirm that by running 
`npm -v` and `node -v`

Comment: Thank you. I've found the answer. I needed to add "C:\Program Files\nodejs" to my Environment variables under PATH.

Answer (score 0):

i have also experienced this.Its probably because of some glitch while installing node.There is work around though.
Try with sudo.
'sudo npm install firebase-tools'. It mighy work for you also.